# Why is System.Console exposing a SetIn method?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, architecture

This is a little something that struck me as I was writing an adapter for the `System.Console` class. Why are the `In`, `Out` and `Error` properties paired to a `SetIn`, `SetOut` and `SetError` method? Why not use the property's setter instead? Is this an architectural decision or is there a limitation that prevents the .NET framework developer from doing this?

Comment: Property setters should not have too many side-effects.

Comment: While I agree with you for the general case, this is still a very opinionated argument. I mean, I don't consider swapping a TextReader as "too many side-effects". This is exactly what I would expect from setting one of these value. Beside, if it really is too much of a side-effect, why expose it through SetIn() in the first place?

Comment: Good question. My guess is something to do with the different security `Attributes` on each.  I wonder if early versions had limitations on the scope of attributes, which forced the designers to use a set method.  Or another idea is that they explicitly wanted to draw attention to the security permissions required.

Comment: Good guess, but after decompiling the code, we can see that they use the same attributes. So this is not it either :-/

Comment: Looks a little different here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs

Comment: I have to confess I have not looked at the reference sources. I only looked at the decompiled source dotPeak and ILspy are giving me. I guess you can submit this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: It's just guessing on my part, so I'd prefer not to answer in case I'm wrong.  Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak for the original author, but there are at least five good reasons to use a set method in conjunction with a property getter (and possibly a protected setter):

1. You need additional parameters (in or out) when setting the value.
2. You need multiple overloads of the setter. Maybe it is common to set some specifically-typed property by string as well as the specific type.
3. You need different attributes or permissions for setting vs. getting.
4. You have different functionality for updating the property vs. setting the value. For example, consider a client-side proxy class that has to update a value from server data in addition to allowing the user to set a value that needs to be propagated to the server.
5. Maybe you want to separate your interfaces for covariance such that you need your getter and setter on different interfaces.

Having said all that, I reviewed the code in dotPeek for the said methods (`SetIn` and `get_In`). I can't find any excuse for not using the setter. The `In` getter has the same permission attributes as the `SetIn` method.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. Even though all of those reasons are perfectly valid, none of them seems to apply to this design decision. Hence, the interrogation I face. Good comment still :)